# Why is Rails the authenticity token the only param that my app is passing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails app built on a scaffold.  For some reason, whenever I try to go to the index page from the edit page, I get the following error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in PostsController#create
```

and the only parameter it has is the authenticity token:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"foobarbazrandomcharactershere"}
```

Both the edit and index actions in the controller are straightforward:

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    if params[:tag]
      @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
     else
      @posts = Post.all
    end
  end
```

Why is it passing the authenticity token and no other parameters?

Comment: I'm confused, you said the error occurs when you attempt to navigate TO the index page FROM the edit page, but the error you displayed says it is in the `create` method, which would only happen on a POST. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I had changed a `link_to` to a `button_to`, and `button_to` was specifying POST by default.  The fix was to add a `:method` argument to `button_to` :

```
<%= button_to 'Home', posts_path, method: 'get' %>
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why do you need to use a button? With correct styling, you can make a link look like a nice-looking button, if that is what you're looking for, and then you don't need to worry about the `method: 'get'` stuff.

Comment: Teeg, you are correct.  I found that using link_to and a styled div worked too, I just wanted to solve the problem instead of using a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It passes that to protect from XSSR: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures.

---

We have to see your edit view. It is trying to access `params[:tag]`, which is not available. I believe that the edit view is distorted, and the form fields are outside of the form tag, and so they are not being sent back. Show the edit view ERB/HAML and the HTML that it generates, then highlight the form element you are trying to submit.

Comment: Admittedly, the OP's title is misleading, but this is not quite what they are asking.